# Como puedo poner IF en jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

estoy trabajando con react, y agregue un sistema de "valorar" la experiencia, quiero que al hacer clic en X estrella redireccione a un lado, y si hace clic en otra X estrella redireccione a otro formulario, hace poco me lo pasaron, pero en *JavaScript* y ahora aca no puedo, lo intenté y no me funcionó ninguna solución de internet.

```
    const thirdExample = {
      size: 40,
      count: 5,
      isHalf: false,
      value: 4,
      color: "blue",
      activeColor: "yellow",
      onChange: (newValue) => {
        console.log(`Example 3: new value is ${newValue}`);
        alert(newValue===1 ? 'redireccion del valor 1' : 'redireccion del valor 1')
      }
    
    
    };
    
    
    export default function Valorar() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ReactStars {...thirdExample} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Tendría que encontrar una alternativa a esto:

```
  if(newValue==1){
  alert('redireccion del valor 1');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos alternativas a un if común, sería un inline if o una condicion booleana que es muy usada en jsx

El inline if sería

```
(condition ? whenTrue: whenFalse)
```

parantesis opcionales pero recomendados.

así que tu coondición:

```
if(newValue==1){
  alert('redireccion del valor 1');
}
```

Esa condición inline quedaría:

```
alert(newValue==1 ? 'redireccion del valor 1' : 'redireccion del valor 2')
```

o con el alert en la condición:

```
newValue==1 ? alert('redireccion del valor 1') : alert('redireccion del valor 2')
```

Tambien puedes concatenar este tipo de condiciones.

```
alert(newValue===1 ? 'redireccion del valor 1' :( newValue===2 ? 'redireccion del valor 2' : ( newValue===3 ? 'redireccion del valor 3' : 'redireccion del valor 4')))
```

---

Tambien es posible utilizar la opcion de una operación booleana que es bastante simple.

```
condicion && whenTrue
```

Y tu condición quedaría:

```
newValue==1 && alert('redireccion del valor 1');
```

Ambas opciones es posible utilizarlas en un jsx sin problema.

Comment: Bien, funciona, pero en todas las que toco me salta la alerta, y no en la que haga clic

Comment: Donde estas colocando tu condición.? podrías editar tu pregúnta y agregar ese fragmento?

Comment: Ahi agregué tu codigo, pero que me da ese error.

Comment: Debes manejar la condición y concatenarla editaré la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, de está manera si funciona, ahora quedaria cambiar el alert para que redireccione, se puede usar la funcion nativa de javascript no?

Comment: Sí puedes utilizarla

Comment: Perdon que reactive, recien pude volver a conectarme con esto, y me quedo una duda, puedo hacer que al seleccionar se quede marcada las estrellas y despues al darle "aceptar" redireccione según?

Comment: Hola, perdon que vuelva a abrir hilo, pero como sería para redireccionar?

Comment: window.location.href= (condiciones...) o window.location= (condiciones...)